# ExecuteNonQuery causes duplicate records in database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a function that updates records using a sql query string and is executed by ExecuteNonQuery.  The issue is that when this function has to update a list of records, it duplicates every insert with the last record in the list.

Based off this question, [Code repeating itself causing duplicate records in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845026/code-repeating-itself-causing-duplicate-records-in-database), I believe it has something to do with multithreading and creating a transaction, but I'm not entirely sure as I'm not very familiar with creating locks, etc.

Where the method is being called:

```
foreach (var detail in report.Details)
        {
            detail.ShiftReportId = report.ShiftReportId;
            UpdateShiftReportDetail(detail);
        }
```

The method:

```
private void UpdateShiftReportDetail(ShiftReportDetail detail)
    {
        StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
        queryString.Append("Update ShiftReportDetails ")
            .Append("Set ShiftReportId = @ShiftReportId, LineNumber = @LineNumber, Produced = @Produced, Scrap = @Scrap, DownTime = @Downtime, Gauge = @Gauge, PerHour = @PerHour, Cast = @Cast, Target = @Target, Variance = @Variance, Notes = @Notes, PrimaryItem = @PrimaryItem, SecondaryItem = @SecondaryItem, Details = @Details, LineID = @LineId")
            .Append(" Where ShiftReportID = @ShiftReportId");

        // Create a connection.
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString.ToString(), connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShiftReportId", detail.ShiftReportId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineNumber", detail.LineNumber);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Produced", detail.Produced);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Scrap", detail.Scrap ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Downtime", detail.DownTime ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gauge", detail.Gauge ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerHour", detail.PerHour ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cast", detail.Cast ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Target", detail.Target ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variance", detail.Variance ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", detail.Notes ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrimaryItem", detail.PrimaryItem ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondaryItem", detail.SecondaryItem ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", detail.Details ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineId", detail.LineId);

            connection.Open();

            // Execute the command.
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `UPDATE` queries should never add or duplicate records. If you're really sure you're not using any `INSERT` or `REPLACE` queries elsewhere, ensure that your database does not contain any triggers. I don't see any multithreading in your code, but you're right that you should not use multithreading with the same ADO.NET connection.

Comment: I'm guessing there is an issue with your SQL, e.g. you need to use `Where ShiftReportDetailID = ` instead of `Where ShiftReportId=`